# Groovy Creates current datetime + x minutes

Tags: groovy

I try to get current date time + 2 minutes with groovy:

```
import groovy.time.*
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.TimeCategory
import groovy.time.TimeCategory

currentDate1 =  new Date()
use( TimeCategory ) {
   after2Mins  = date + 2.minutes
}
log.info after2Mins
```

and I got this error:

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: date for
>   class: Script8 error at line: 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be:

```
import groovy.time.*
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.TimeCategory
import groovy.time.TimeCategory

def currentDate1 =  new Date()
use( TimeCategory ) {
   after2Mins = currentDate1 + 2.minutes
}
println after2Mins
```

You're missing `def` before `currentDate1` and used `date` instead of `currentDate1` in `TimeCategory` closure.